# Can't port C# code to managed C++ implementing IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, c++, .net, managed

This part. Commented code is cs. 
On compile catch an error:

```
Error   78
error C3766: 'Sample::NoteInfo' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'System::String ^System::ComponentModel::IDataErrorInfo::default::get(System::String ^)'
d:\dev\docstreet\sample\pointInfoStoreClass.h   100
```

What's incorrect? Why VS compiler consider this not implemented?

```
//Returns an error description set for the item&#39;s property
//String^ IDataErrorInfo.this[String^ columnName] {
//  get {
//      return GetColumnError(columnName);
//  }
//}

public: property String^ IDataErrorInfo[String^] {
    virtual String^ get(String^ index) override {
        return GetColumnError(index);
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
public ref class NoteInfo : IDataErrorInfo {
        int fDay;
        int fMonth;
        int fYear;
        int fNoteID;
        //References the item's owner
        ProjectNotes^ owner;
        //Stores error descriptions for the Day, Month, Year and NoteID properties
        Hashtable^ propertyErrors;
        //Stores an error description for the item
        String^ fNoteError;


    public: NoteInfo(int noteID, int day, int month, int year) {
            fNoteID = noteID;
            fDay = day;
            fMonth = month;
            fYear = year;
            //Set errors to empty strings
            propertyErrors = gcnew Hashtable();
            propertyErrors->Add('Day', '');
            propertyErrors->Add('Month', '');
            propertyErrors->Add('Year', '');
            propertyErrors->Add('NoteID', '');
            fNoteError = '';
            Owner = nullptr;
        }

    public: property int NoteID {
            int get() { return fNoteID; }
            void set(int value) {
                if(fNoteID == value) return;
                fNoteID = value;
            }
        }

    public: void ClearErrors() {
            SetColumnError('Day', '');
            SetColumnError('Month', '');
            SetColumnError('Year', '');
            fNoteError = '';
        }

        //Sets an error for an item's property
    public: void SetColumnError(String^ elem, String^ error) {
            if(propertyErrors->ContainsKey(elem)) {
                if((String^)propertyErrors[elem] == error) return;
                propertyErrors[elem] = error;
            }
        }

        //Gets an error for an item's property
    public: String^ GetColumnError(String^ elem) {
            if(propertyErrors->ContainsKey(elem))
                return (String^)propertyErrors[elem];
            else
                return '';
        }

        //The owner collection
    internal: property ProjectNotes^ Owner {
            ProjectNotes^ get() { return owner; }
            void set(ProjectNotes^ value) { owner = value; }
        }


#pragma region IDataErrorInfo Members

        //Returns an error description set for the item's property
        //String^ IDataErrorInfo.this[String^ columnName] {
        //  get {
        //      return GetColumnError(columnName);
        //  }
        //}

        public: property String^ IDataErrorInfo[String^] {
            virtual String^ get(String^ index) override {
                return GetColumnError(index);
            }
        }

        //Returns an error description set for the current item
    public: property String^ Error {
            virtual String^ get() { return fNoteError; }

        }
#pragma endregion
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the C# and the C++/CLI languages require a special name for the indexer of a class to allow the compiler to recognize it as the indexer.  C# uses *this*, C++/CLI uses the **default** keyword.  The MSDN Library calls it "Item" to add to the confusion, somewhat inevitably since the name depends on the language.  So it must look like this:

```
public: property String^ default[String^] {
            virtual String^ get(String^ index) {
                // etc...
            }
        }
```

Comment: For class level indexers, use 'default' for property level indexers use the name of the property.